# Get browser width and height append divs jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, browser, append, browser-width

I'm trying to get the browser width and height and append two different DIV's to two different positions using jQuery.

DIV ONE should be absolute positioned, 40px from the left and 40px from the bottom of the browser window whilst DIV TWO should be 40px from the right and 40px from the bottom, no matter what device is looking at the webpage (so must work on iPad, iPhone's etc.).

I also have content (images, child divs and text) sitting within both div's but I just haven't a clue how to approach this as I'm useless with jQuery.

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Use $(window).height(); $(window).width(); for finding width and height of browser window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for that (the positioning, at least). CSS has enough tricks.

Don't use *absolute* positioning, use fixed:

```
#div-1, #div-2 {position:fixed;}
#div-1 {left:40px; bottom;40px;}
#div-2 {right:40px; bottom;40px}
```

With `position:fixed`, the left, right, top, and bottom properties refer to how far the respective edge of the fix-positioned object is from the respective edge of the viewport.

...So it won't matter where you apped your divs. Just append them to the body:

```
var myDivsHtml = howeverYouGetYourDivs();
$('body').append(myDivsHtml)
```

Comment: I have made a serious booboo with this question and I have accepted your answer because you have in escense answered it, however its not completely what I was looking for as I mis-wrote the question, check this question for my full problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995356/get-width-and-height-of-screen-window-and-height-of-div-jquery

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for fixed positioning and not absolute.

Just use CSS for this

```
.div1{
   position:fixed;
   bottom:40px;
   left:40px;
}
.div2{
   position:fixed;
   bottom:40px;
   right:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var $body = $("body");
    $("<div/>").css({
        "position":"fixed",
        "bottom":"40px",
        "left":"40px"
        }).appendTo($body);
    $("<div/>").css({
        "position":"fixed",
        "bottom":"40px",
        "right":"40px"
        }).appendTo($body);
});
```