# Get width and height of screen window and height of div jquery

Tags: jquery, html, browser, append, browser-width

In plain English this is the jQuery functionality i'm after:

I need to get the width and the height of the browser window and then get the height of `.banner` div (height is automatic). If the height of `.banner` div is higher than that of the height of the browser window append `.title` div and `.social` div to the body otherwise display `.title` div and .social div within `.banner` div.

How do I then style the two divs accordingly (`.title` and `.social`)?

**EDIT:**
This is my on page load code in HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
   <div class="title">
      <!--to be positioned 40px from the left-->
   </div>
   <div class="social">
      <!--to be positioned 40px from the right-->
   </div>

   <img src="URL"/> <!-- Image determines height of DIV uses max-width -->

</div>
```

Comment: in plain english, what have you tried?

Comment: have you tried $(window).height(), $(window).width(), $('.banner').height(), etc.?

Comment: Well I've edited the post to include my HTML code but I have tried producing an if statement based on resolution but isn't robust enough as I have to duplicate all of the divs. I just don't know how to write jQuery to get something to work...

Comment: For reference this is some code I worked with but just wasn't efficient enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617762/jquery-if-statement-based-on-browser-width-and-a-divs-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height(); //Gives you the browser viewport height
var bannerHeight = $(".banner").height();

if (bannerHeight > windowHeight) {
    $("body").append($('.title'));
    $("body").append($('.social'));

    //Then you can style them using jQuery .css
    //Example
    $('.title').css('color', 'red');
}
else {
    //Display .title and .social in your .banner div
}
```

- jQuery .height info: http://api.jquery.com/height/
- jQuery .css info: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: This is brilliant. Works a charm. I will accept your answer but just wondered, how can I update the code on browser resize? So that when the browser is resized (smaller for example) on a desktop the script refreshes and adjusts itself accordingly?

Comment: You just need to create an event listener using jQuery .resize().

Example can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Cheers Marc. Couldn't get it working by wrapping your code with this: $(window).resize(function() { ... your code here ... }); I'm such a novice when it come to jQuery. It would be nice if I could get this working but I understand this wasn't apart of my original question :)

Comment: What part of .resize does not work? Is it ever calling the .resize function when you resize the window? Or does the appending and such not work?

Comment: The appending code you provided doesn't work with it. Not sure how to test if the .resize function is being called or not.

Comment: Instead of     
    $("body").append($('.title'));

Try giving the div an id such as <div id="titlediv" class="title">
Then you can do something like:
    $("body").append($('#title'));

In order to see if your resize function is being called, just put an alert() within the function. Such as:
    alert("Resize has been called");

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12440/discussion-between-marc-b-and-egr103)

Answer (score 0):

Use these functions:

```
$(window).height();
$(window).width();
$('.banner').width();
$('.banner').height();
$("#tostyle").addClass('someclass');
```

etc

Comment: Thats great but I'm pretty useless with writing jQuery code so how would I transform that into a working code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

update dynamicly the elements :

```
$(function(){
    var divheight = $('.banner').height(); // div current height

    // handle the resize event
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if($(this).height() < divheight) {
            $('.title').appendTo($('body'));
            $('.social').appendTo($('body'));
            $('.banner').hide();
        } else {
            $('.title').appendTo($('.banner'));
            $('.social').appendTo($('.banner'));
            $('.banner').show();
        }
    });
});
```

*the code is deliberately not simplify for better readability*